# Use ISSET from some of the examples here on stackoverflow Error on the Code

Tags: php, mysql, get, isset

I Dont think I wrote the code correctly. Can someone look at this? I am new to php!

```
<?php 
// Create Connection
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','test123','joomla');

// Check Connection
if(mysqli_connect_errno($connect)) {
    echo 'Failed to connect to DataBase| '. mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
```

I added `if(issets($_GET['rp_id']))` to the if rp_id does not exist in the url parameter - it just closes the database

```
<?php 
if(issets($_GET['rp_id]')) {
    $rp_id = htmlspecialchars($_GET["rp_id"]);
    // open record with evdet_id =$rp_id
    $result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM n0dap_jevents_vevdetail WHERE    evdet_id =".$rp_id);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)): 
        $value = $row['google_map'];
        echo $value;
        endwhile;
    }

    $connect->close();
    //if the rp_id does exist the go ahead and run the top otherwise close it.  
} else { 
    $connect->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). htmlspecialchars is **NOT** a defense against this.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(issets($_GET['rp_id]))
```

Looks like you made a typo on isset().

Call to undefined function issets()

This means you're trying to call issets() as a function, which it is not.
The function that you are looking for is isset(). If you replace issets() with isset(), you will not longer get that error message.